# Wix: Adding Icon to the start menu application folder

Tags: wix

I'm looking for a way to add an icon to the start menu application folder using Wix. I already know how to add icons for shortcuts but the application folder doesn't appear to be a shortcut. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't shared any code, there is an example

```
<Component Id="MainAppFile" Guid="*">
        <File Id="MainAppExecutable" Source="$(var.AppDir)$(var.AppFile)" KeyPath="yes">
          <Shortcut Id="StartMenuAppShortcut"
                    Name="$(var.ProductName)"
                    Advertise="yes"
                    Directory="ApplicationProgramsFolder"
                    WorkingDirectory="INSTALLLOCATION">
            <Icon Id="StartMenuIcon.ico" SourceFile="..\icon.ico"/>
          </Shortcut>
          <Shortcut Id="DesktopAppShortcut"
                    Name="$(var.ProductName)"
                    Advertise="yes"
                    Directory="DesktopFolder"
                    WorkingDirectory="INSTALLLOCATION" >
            <Icon Id="DesktopIcon.ico" SourceFile="..\icon.ico"/>
          </Shortcut>
        </File>
        <RemoveFolder Id="CleanupAppShortcut" Directory="ApplicationProgramsFolder" On="uninstall"/>
</Component>
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm running Win10 and what I'm seeing is a mix of folders and shortcuts on the same start menu list - not just a list of folders. It's the shortcuts that have icons attached. Folders don't have icons attached.

Comment: @namg_engr Not sure, that I get did. If need to place each shortcut inside separate folder, you have to use a correct directory, not the same one for all shortcuts